# Checkbox field for nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form with a nested `fields_for` form for each person. The idea is the user can select which person to add to the booking using a checkbox

```
<%= form_for(@booking) do |f| %>    
  <% people.each do |person| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :appointments do |builder| %>
      <p>                                     
        <%= builder.hidden_field :event_id, :value => @event.id %>  
        <%= builder.check_box :person_id, :value => person.id %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The trouble is, the checkbox value is always "1" If i replace check_box with text_field, I get all the fields displayed correctly, with the right values, and the form submits through to create the booking.

How can I get the `check_box` field to display with the `person.id` not 1 as the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing incorrect parameters to the [`check_box` helper function](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box).

Try this:

```
<%= builder.check_box :person_id, {}, person.id %>
```

Comment: Cool.  Thanks! so check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")  I still can't quite see how the two line up, but what you have there works for me.

Comment: Basically what I have above is just syntactic sugar given to you by the Rails view helpers when you create that `builder` object. The method actually getting called is the one from the documentation I linked.

Comment: ok, thanks - its good to try and understand rather than just get stuff fixed.  Your help is much appreciated :)